# meaning of "deepen relationship" and "deep"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I have a question about the meaning of the verb "*deepen*" and by extension the adjective "*deep*" in this [New York Times](https://www.nytimes.com/2017/05/16/world/middleeast/israel-trump-classified-intelligence-russia.html?_r=0) article:

> Israel has full confidence in our intelligence-sharing relationship with the United States and looks forward to ***deepening*** that relationship in the years ahead under President Trump.

Most dictionaries define "*deepen*" as make something more "*deep*".  So it comes down to the meaning of "*deep*".  I check this [dictionary](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/deep), but I don't know which definition would work.   Any suggestions from native speakers?

Comment: #12 comes pretty close. Making the relationship fuller, more thorough, more complete. Now, you have to look up those words. Insofar is it borrows here from the language of personal relationships, **deepen** would imply more complete trust between the parties. Insofar as it draws from the language of spydom, **deepen** could mean sharing even more information, even the sort that was previously considered too secret to share.

Comment: The opposite is 'shallow' which in this kind of context would mean 'superficial'.

Comment: What exactly is your question??

Answer (score 1):

In the usage in your example

> looks forward to **deepening** that relationship

**deepening** has the main meaning of **strengthening** or **solidifying** the relationship and possibly creating a grater level of *interdependency* which may be achieved by additional intelligence sharing either through amount, breadth, or depth.